# Powershell Invoke-WebRequest returns array of objects but processes as if there is only 1

Tags: powershell, get, invoke-webrequest

```
$path = "https://api.statuspage.io/v1/pages/$page_id/$endpoint"
$req  = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $path -Method GET
```

This request returns an array of objects (50+). I can see this by running a `Write-Host $req`

Problem is, when I try something like

```
foreach($i in $req) {
  Write-Host $i
}
```

I am given the entire object. And similarly, if I run `Write-Host $req.length` I am given `1`. What gives?

Additionally, there is no way to run something like

```
$global:res = ConvertFrom-Json $req
```

Because it's already being returned as a JSON

Comment: what do you get from `$Req.GetType()` or from `$Req | Get-Member`?

Comment: GetType() gives me `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HtmlWebResponseObject` and `Get-Member` gives me a bynch of stuff `void...bool..int..type.. etc`

Comment: What if you run `$singleReq = $req | select-object -first 1; $singleReq.GetType()` ? That is a quick way to convert an array response to get the first item (or same item if not an array). Also, it's possible that powershell is following links...try using `-UseBasicParsing` to keep it from parsing HTML

Comment: It gives me this: `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HtmlWebResponseObject`

Comment: Try `$req.Content | ConvertFrom-Json`

Comment: add 
$page_id = ???
$endpoint = ???

Comment: @Theo that did the trick! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @vin_Bin87 - i see that `Theo` pointed out how to deal with your actual objects. kool! glad to know that you got it working as needed ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intent is to **parse the JSON text into (nested) *objects* (`[pscustomobject]` graphs)** anyway, you can simply **use [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) rather than [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest)**, because `Invoke-RestMethod` has [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) *built in*, in a manner of speaking:

```
$path = "https://api.statuspage.io/v1/pages/$page_id/$endpoint"

# Retrieves JSON *and* parses it into objects.
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $path -Method GET
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `$req  = Invoke-WebRequest ...`

`Invoke-WebRequest` returns a *single* object, namely and instance of [`BasicHtmlWebResponseObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.BasicHtmlWebResponseObject) (PowerShell [Core] v6+) / [`HtmlWebResponseObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HtmlWebResponseObject) (Windows PowerShell), which is a wrapper object with metadata that stores the *content* of the response received in the `.Content` property.

In your case, `.Content` contains JSON as a *single string*, which `ConvertFrom-Json` can parse into a nested *object*(s).

To parse this JSON string into one or more (potentially nested) objects (`[pscustomobject]` graphs):

```
$result = ConvertFrom-Json $req.Content
```

Note that even `$result = ConvertFrom-Json $req` would work, because when a response object is implicitly *stringified*, it interpolates to the value of its `.Content` property.

As [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) points out in a comment, you can also use the pipeline:

```
$result = $req | ConvertFrom-Json
```